# How to creating an addin for multiple Office programs?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, add-in, office-interop

I want to develop addins for Office (Outlook,Word and Excel). The code will be almost the same. The difference is only for retrieve a document (mail for Outlook, document for Word,graphic/chart for Excel.

Should I develop 3 addins and therefore I will have 3 installations for my users. Or can I develop only 1 addin and add a condition somewhere?

Comment: You can restrict yourself to one AddIn. We have written an AddIn that spans Word,Excel,Visio,Outlook,... and we haven't had any problems so far. Although the choice is still up to you.

Comment: @User999999 How you do that ? What type of project you selected ?

Comment: Just a standard `class library`containing modules.

Comment: @User999999 I do that. I have three addins and one class library. My addins is only for create button on the ribbon for launch my code. But I have always three addin. I don't understand how you can have only one addin !

Comment: We are using a combination of `Reflection` and `AddinExpress` (there probably are free versions for this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You possibly need 3 different `AddIn` classes, since every platform has it's own format and parameters and you might want to deviate some logic, though there is nothing to stop you integrating the three add-ins in one.

Another option is to make a class library that only uses the general Office assembly, and include that library into your other projects.

For the deployment: you can't use ClickOnce out of the box for that, since ClickOnce only supports a single Office program per installation. You can tweak the installation though, as explained on this article on MSDN: [Deploying Multiple Office 2010 Projects in One Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff951700%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: What type of project I have to choose for my global solution ?

Comment: I would start with just any Office products' template in Visual Studio. Doesn't really matter I believe.

Comment: @mosflex: Need more help?

Comment: yes I have already an addin Outlook. What I should add and where? A new class and what type?

Comment: @mosflex: Did you check the documentation on MSDN? It is very useful.

Comment: You told me to add class but in this documentation are projects. So I have to add 3 projects ?

Comment: I think it is possible to join the three in one assembly too, but as suggested, you could have three libraries. The important part is the changing the deployment to register the add-in to the three applications. So start making a Office add-in and alter the ClickOnce manifest files.

Comment: Hi I tried to deploy multiple Office  2010 projects in one package with the tutoriel but in the step 29 :Type the following command all on one line to re-sign the application manifest: mage -sign MultiSolutionAddInInstaller.dll.manifest -certfile MultiSolutionAddInInstaller_TemporaryKey.pfx. I had an error : unrecognized type file for the manifest. Have you any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: @mosflex: No, never seen it. I have seens some issues with `(r)` for exampe in the manifest, but not sure about this one. Didn't google yield any useful result?

Comment: No not really. I'm still looking !

Comment: @mosflex Glad you found it. I just realized I totally forgot to upvote your question. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

VSTO doesn't supoport creating multi-host add-ins. The possible ways are:

1. Develop an add-in which implements [IDTExtensibility2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300893(v=vs.71).aspx) interface without VSTO.
2. Use third-party tools such as Add-in Express that support creating multi-host add-ins.

Adding multiple *AddIn* classes to the extisting VSTO based add-ins is not a convinient way to go. At least, you will not be able to debug the code

Comment: It does, but the deployment doesn't. I have got it working using a class library containing the addin base class and ribbon for example.

Comment: It is an undocumented feature which can be shut down at any time. VSTO doesn't support support creating multi-host add-ins officially.

Comment: Are you kidding? Could you please provide me with a link where multiple add-ins in the single project are described?

Comment: I tested Patrick's solution it works but the automatic update not. I think Add-in Express is the best solution but the software is not free.